# How to write a program to find the fastest working proxy server?

Tags: proxy

My college has 5-6 proxy servers and occasionally some of them are down or slow. I would like to write a program that would help me determine the fastest available proxy server. Does there exist any application for this already?

Comment: Do you want to know if such a program exists ? Then you should ask on superuser.com, since it is clearly not programming related. If you want to write such a program, you will need to be more specific - what part are you having problems with, and what technology are you using ?

Comment: @driis : I am a student and I have no idea which technology to use to make it. If someone give me some ideas then I would start working in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a quick Google reveals that this kind of software [already exists](http://elite-proxy-switcher.smartcode.com/info.html). I haven't tried it though, so I can't say anything about the quality of those.

If you decide to make one yourself, here is a rough sketch on how you could do it with .NET:

1. Maintain a list of proxy server candidates
2. Issue requests (to the same resources for all servers) through these proxies using HttpWebRequest and setting the Proxy property.
3. Measure average request time.
4. Set the browser proxy setting to the server that turned out to be fastest.